# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'slim'

Tags: python, tensorflow

こんにちは
私はnsynthのトレーニングを試しているのですが、エラーが発生してしまいます。もし解決策などがありましたらご教授ください
環境は
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
magenta-gpu 0.3.12 
tensorflow-gpu 1.11.0

```
＄bazel run //magenta/models/nsynth/baseline:train -- --train_path=//home/nekome/tffile.tfrecords ---logdir=//home/nekome/Logdire
WARNING: Processed legacy workspace file /home/nekome/magenta/tools/bazel.rc. This file will not be processed in the next release of Bazel. Please read https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6319 for further information, including how to upgrade.
INFO: Analysed target //magenta/models/nsynth/baseline:train (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //magenta/models/nsynth/baseline:train up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline/train
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.059s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline/train '--trINFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:99] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:1407] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nekome/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/8d760b4887a3a97dbc093bfa28201502/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline/train.runfiles/__main__/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline/train.py", line 23, in <module>
    from magenta.models.nsynth import reader
  File "/home/nekome/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/8d760b4887a3a97dbc093bfa28201502/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline/train.runfiles/__main__/magenta/models/nsynth/reader.py", line 24, in <module>
    from magenta.models.nsynth import utils
  File "/home/nekome/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/8d760b4887a3a97dbc093bfa28201502/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/magenta/models/nsynth/baseline/train.runfiles/__main__/magenta/models/nsynth/utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    slim = tf.contrib.slim
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'slim'
```

どうすれば解決できますか？
問題のutils.pyというファイルは[こちら](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NLzwn0dD5nHj8x-qIIBSsQeMqYJpTLV8/view?usp=sharing)です

Comment: tensorflowのバージョンはいくつになりますでしょうか？`pip list`を実行し、tensorflowと書いてある行がなんと出力されているかご教示頂けますでしょうか

Comment: tensorflowのcpu版でしょうか？　cpu版は入れていません（一応tensorflow1.11.0をインストールして実行してみましたが、その場合も同様のエラーが発生しました）

Answer (score 1):

この質問は、`Magenta`の開発環境の構築の質問と思われます。質問のようなエラーが発生する場合は、パッケージに問題が生じている可能性が高いため、新たに仮想環境を作成して、Magentaのホームページ（https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta）の手順に従ってインストールするのがいいと思われます。数分でインストールできます。

`Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`でPython3を使用する場合は、以下のようにします。

まず、`venv`をインストールできていなければ`apt`でインストールします。

```
sudo apt install python3-venv
```

それから、`Magenta`の開発環境をインストールしたいディレクトリーに移動します。
次に｀magenta`のリポジロリ−をクーロンして、そのディレクトリーに移動します。

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta.git
cd ./magenta
```

仮想環境を作成します。

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m venv env
```

仮想環境を有効化してから、`magenta-gpu`をインストールします。`magenta-gpu`をpipでインストールすることにより、`tensorflow`等他の必要なパッケージもインストールされます。

```
source env/bin/activate
pip3 install magenta-gpu
```

`Magenta`の開発環境をテストします。

```
bazel test //magenta/...
```

`Executed 1 out of 55 tests: 54 tests pass and 1 fails locally.`となればOKです。//magenta/music:musicnet_io_test は、Python3の場合は失敗します。

仮想環境を出る時は以下のコマンドを実行します。
    deactivate

次回以降は、`Magenta`の開発環境のディレクトリーに移動して、以下で仮想環境を有効化してから作業をします。

```
source env/bin/activate
```

なお、仮想環境の詳しい説明については、公式チュートリアルの [12. 仮想環境とパッケージ](http://ttps://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/tutorial/venv.html)をみてください。また、Python2, Anaconda(Miniconda)を使いたい場合も、仮想環境を作成できます。その場合は、それぞれのマニュアルで確認してください。

Comment: 返信遅くなりました申し訳ありません　おかげさまで解決できそうです　ありがとうございました